# ¿Cómo manejar el resultado del nueva recaptcha V3?

Tags: php, formularios, seguridad, recaptcha

He actualizado el recaptcha típico de buscar señales de tráfico y coches tan tedioso, por el nuevo recaptcha V3. Se supone que valida tu interacción en la web, tus clicks, la posición del ratón...

Cuando llamas al servicio de google, este te devuelve una respuesta que contiene una puntuación, de 0 a 1, siendo 0 'eres un robot' y 1 'eres una persona'.

Yo he establecido que a partir de 0,5 eres un usuario corriente interactuando con mi formulario:

```
if($httpResponse) {
    if ($httpResponse->success===true){
        $httpResponseParameters = json_decode($httpResponse, true);
        if ($httpResponseParameters['score'] >= 0.5) {
            //Eres una persona!
        }
    }     
}
```

Pero, que ocurriría si una persona por cualquier causa, obtiene una puntuación inferior, como por ejemplo, al interactuar en la web en modo incógnito (se obtiene 0,1).

¿Que podría hacer en esos casos?. ¿Debería pedirle al usuario que realice un nuevo recaptcha manual para verificar que es una persona?

Comment: La idea del recaptcha manual es una buenta alternativa si falla el v3. Y mas bien cambiaría la forma de verlo como: implementar v2 y ver si vale la pena implementar v3. Respecto del score, si ese número representa una probabilidad, 0.5 equivale a "no tengo idea si sos un robot o un humano".

Comment: @Juan Antes estaba usando v2, pero en cuanto a usabilidad llegaba a ser molesto verificar ciertos objetos cada vez que se hacía login. En cuanto a lo que dices de que 0.5 estaría interpretando que no tiene ni idea, tiene cierto sentido, lo correcto sería que fuera >0.5 y asi, en caso de duda, pues el recaptcha no es válido.

Comment: Entiendo lo que decis y estoy de acuerdo, vos conoces tu caso mejor que nadie. El tema del score es el que no me cierra del todo, y no vi mucha orientación en el sitio de Recaptcha. Y me parece que para determinar que es un humano debería pedirse 0.8 o 0.9. Sobre todo si se implementa un v2 como back up digamos. No me queda claro si pedir un 0.5 es mucho mas util que no poner el recaptcha.